# AngularJS: Multiple dropdowns

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I am writing code for dropdowns. Each row has the same dropdown. This is the code

**HTML:**

```
<tr ng-repeat='item in items>
    <td>
         <span>{{item.profName}}</span>
         <span ng-if="!item.editProf">
             <img src="images/img1.png" class="img"          
                         ng-click="editProf({{item.pId}})"></img>
        </span>
        <div ng-if="item.editProf">
              <select ng-model="prof" class="form-control" name= "profName" 
                      ng-options="prof.name as prof.value for prof in lookups.prof" 
                  ng-Blur="updateProf([item.pId])">
              </select>
         </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Script:**

```
$scope.editProf = function(pId)
    {
        var profIndex = $scope.profIndexList[pId];
        var profObj = $scope.profList[profIndex];
        profObj.editProf = true;
        $scope.prof = profObj.profName;
    }
```

When I click on the image it will go to edit mode. When I select an option, it will go to read only mode again. But, when I open two dropdowns, it shows the same option for two dropdowns (When I select an option from the second dropdown, the same option is updated in the first dropdown due to the same scope). How to resolve this issue?
Help me.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.cols = [{
      col_id: 'test1',
      col_name: 'First'
    }, {
      col_id: 'test2',
      col_name: 'Second'
    }];

    $scope.col = "test1";
    
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select 
      ng-options="col.col_id as col.col_name for col in cols"
      ng-model="col">
    </select>
    <select 
      ng-options="col.col_id as col.col_name for col in cols"
      ng-model="col">
    </select>
  

  </div>
```

**JSFiddle:**  http://jsfiddle.net/x8rq2pda/23/

Comment: Do you see 2 selects in your example code ?

Comment: Where is the second dropdown? Please provide a complete code example.

Comment: Well, they obviously have the same selection, since they're all bound to `prof`, using `ng-model="prof"`. You need to bind each select to a different model. Something like `ng-model="item.prof"`

Comment: Sorry, I have ng-repeat on tr tag. updated my question.

Comment: Put some code from controller or create fiddle with all code.

Answer (score 0):

You should always remeber to have a dot(.) in your ngModel attribute or else you will always have this issue.

You can do the following.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/x8rq2pda/24/)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.cols = [{
      col_id: 'test1',
      col_name: 'First'
    }, {
      col_id: 'test2',
      col_name: 'Second'
    }];

    $scope.col = {
        dropdown1 : "test1",
        dropdown2 : "test1"
    };

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select 
      ng-options="col.col_id as col.col_name for col in cols"
      ng-model="col.dropdown1">
    </select>
    <select 
      ng-options="col.col_id as col.col_name for col in cols"
      ng-model="col.dropdown2">
    </select>
  </div>
```

----EDIT----

Try this.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <p>{{item.profName}}
        <select ng-options="profVals for profVals in item.profVals" ng-model="item.selected"></select>
    </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',

function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        profName: "ABC",
        profEdit: true,
        profVals: ["First", "Second", "Third"]
    }, {
        profName: "DEF",
        profEdit: true,
        profVals: ["First", "Second", "Third"]
    }, {
        profName: "XYZ",
        profEdit: false,
        profVals: ["First", "Second", "Third"]
    }];
}]);
```

The selected value will be available in item.selected.
[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/x8rq2pda/26/)

Comment: In this case you have two select tags. But in my case I have only one select tag. How can I set   *ng-model="col.dropdown1 or 2*